# Generating JSON with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I need to convert a small chunk of HTML in a handlebars template into a part of a JSON object.  Here's the relevant portion of the  Handlebars template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each props.items}}
    <li>
      <a>{{name}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I need the final output in the JSON object to be either an array of strings (one per line of the final code) OR a single string with no line breaks.  Instead, I'm getting the whole final block as a single string but *with line breaks* - which makes the JSON invalid.

I don't own the Handlebars template or the JSON so I can't change either of those.

Here's what my code looks like currently:

```
var fileContents = Plugins.fs.readFileSync(hbsPath,  "utf8");

//Next line is my latest attempt to close each line with quotes, 
//inject a newline and start new line with quotes.
//It doesn't work - the newline isn't inserted.
//I've also tried \n\r, \r\n, \r

fileContents = fileContents.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "\",\n\"");

var template = hbs.compile(fileContents);
var thisProps = {props: props};
return new hbs.SafeString(template(thisProps));
```

If I simply write the returned string to the console, it looks right, but when I create the JSON file with it, the unterminated strings are flagged as invalid.

**Update**: Here's where the JSON comes into the picture:

```
{
    "code" : [{{renderSnippet "MyPartial" MyModel }}]
}
```

This is the file that Handlebars processes and the partial inside the `{{ }}` is replaced with the string that comes out of Handlebars.  That string is the problem - it includes line breaks which make it invalid JSON.  I need to either make it a single string with no line breaks, or an array of strings with each line as a separate string.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: You should show how you create the JSON string.

Comment: @t.niese: Handlebars is doing that.  That's the problem - I'm not controlling it.  The last three lines in my second snippet above handle the string generation from the Handlebars template in my first snippet above.

Comment: Handlebars returns a String but does not create JSON. Why do you expect that it creates JSON?

Comment: Right.  I get that.  I amended the question to show where the JSON comes in.  The string that comes out of Handlebars is stored in the JSON template in place of the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in the comment, Handlebars does not create JSON. Handlebars is a template engine targeting html, so it will only work well with html or languages having the same or similar escaping. You would need to store the result of `{{renderSnippet "MyPartial" MyModel }}` in an Object that you convert to JSON.

Something like that:

```
var renderSnippedTpl = Handlebars.compile('{{renderSnippet "MyPartial" MyModel }}');

var obj = {
   code : [renderSnippedTpl({/*required params*/})]
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

Comment: OK, thanks.  This helped me figure out a direction in which to go.