# How to fix error JSON - Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'

Tags: json, string, syntax-error, payload

I have sent my payload to jsonformatter.org but when I try to make it pretty, I the see the error message below:

```
Parse error on line 8:
...Items": [
        {{#each data.items}}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'
```

The payload is this one:

```
{
    "TimeStamp": "{{timestamp}}",
    "SourceOrderId": "{{data.sourceOrderId}}",
    "OrderId": "{{data.orderId}}",
    "PrintedComponentId": "{{data.sourceItemId}}",
    "OrderStatus": "reprinted",
    "Items": [
        {{#each data.items}}
                        {
                                 "Barcode":"{{barcode}}",
                                 "SourceItemId": "{{sourceItemId}}",
                                 "Sku": "{{sku}}",
                                 "Status":"{{status}}",
                                 "ReprintCount":"{{reprintCount}}",
                                 "quantity": "{{quantity}}",
                                 "Scanned":"{{scanned}}"
                       {{#if @last}}
        }
                      {{else}}
    },
    {{/if}}
                      {{/each}}
]
}
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: That’s not JSON, so an error would be expecte. Although that error looks like it might come from the code that is supposed to “generate” the JSON? If the latter is the case, remove the inappropriate json tags and tag with the generating language/environment.

Comment: It's not structured as Json, json should have key:value structure suggest you to use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# it will point all the errors.

Comment: @InUser, thank you for your help. It seems the element {{#each data.items}} is a js. handlebar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683854/generating-json-with-handlebars

Comment: Kudo @InUser!!!